# Client wants to share profit and license for a project

Tags: contracts, clients, licensing, customer-relations, intellectual-property

Initially, the client hired me for a project without mentioning any profit-sharing or assistance with commercialization. However, after investing approximately 30 hours into the project, I've produced a solution that far exceeds their expectations. Now, they're proposing a partnership where they would take 50% of the sales revenue and contribute to the selling process.

I currently possess the license for this solution. Throughout our collaboration, which has included three video calls (every call is free), the client insists that the time spent explaining their vision should be considered as sharing ideas with me. However, I have concerns that their involvement may be more of an opportunistic move, given that I've been working on a similar project for the past seven years.

I should add that the client is not fully open about what he wants in this regard. I am worried that he wants to clarify these new terms before he pays for the solution. He hinted that he probably wants a written contract.

Am I obliged to share the license and share profit under these new terms? Additionally, what potential issues could arise if I agree to share it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When considering a "partnership" of any kind, one needs to evaluate the proven skills of the other partners. In a situation like this, they are asking you to take on risk based on their ability to sell the solution.

What is their track record of selling? Do they have a solid sales and marketing plan? What is their record on being able to sell investors and bankers on providing financing for their venture? If they are not able to get the financing, that says a lot about their ability to generate the sales.

Note: In any market, only 2-3 people out of 10 who want our products are able to pay for them. We will have people ask us to "build it, let them sell it, and share the profits." Most are not able to generate the sales. I've tried a couple, got no sales.

At this point in the project, it sounds like you neither have a written contract, nor any up-front down payment or payment for the hours spent. That means that you have zero, repeat, zero obligation to them for anything.

The "knowledge" that they have shared with you is most likely "generally known or available" by "third parties" and thus, is not "protected company secrets."

Successful salespeople are able to sell investors and bankers on providing the funding needed to pay you in full the amounts you need to develop their product. They are then able to fully own what they bought from you and sell it keeping all the profits for themselves. In other words, successful salespeople don't need to share profits with you.

Comment: David, thank you so much for such an amazing answer.

Comment: Could you clarify this: “ The "knowledge" that they have shared with you is most likely "generally known or available" by "third parties" and thus, is not "protected company secrets." ?

Comment: You are right; zero payment so far. I am taking the risk to spend all this time without any financial risk on their part. If I wasn’t successful, I didn’t receive anything.

Comment: @F.Zer When I sign an NDA, most include phrases like that for information that is not protected by the NDA. The point of that sentence is to say that they most likely did not share any information on those video calls that puts you under any obligation. They might have shared some hopes and dreams, but that is not hard company information that needs protection. I've signed a lot of NDA's and gotten extremely small amounts of hard company information. Most information was readily available or was a hope that might never happen.

Comment: Thank you, David. Yes, what they have shared fall into the category of “dreams and hopes”. Nice way to put it. Sorry for the follow-up question, but I am not familiar with this. When you say: “ I've signed a lot of NDA's and gotten extremely small amounts of hard company information.” if I understand correctly, even though you signed an NDA, they didn’t tell you really confidential information. Even in that context, confidential info wasn’t disclosed. So, without an NDA I should suppose the chances are even smaller.

Comment: Hi David, I spoke with the client. Even though he didn't make any upfront payment he said: "Ideas are the important thing; if I didn't tell you that, this wouldn't have happened. Otherwise, you would have done that already. I want to pay for the software and then always share 50/50 any future income about this".

Comment: "I pushed you to do this, and that was important to move this forward." I explained that I can't split the license with him, and replied: "Ok, I will learn from that in the future. I will make written contracts everytime. At least, I expect you to make a discount to me". "You could make so much money from this in the future"

Comment: I do realize that the fact that he wanted that so hard pushed me to think above and beyond, but giving half of the rights to my license for 30 days of work...He didn't take any risk upfront. About that he said: "You wouldn't pursue that if you didn't think that was possible".

Comment: The last thing he said: "I did mention briefly that I wanted to share 50/50 while we were discussing". Yes, but you didn't ask me properly about that, I replied.

Comment: @F.Zer Ideas are a "dime a dozen." The value is not in an idea, but in the implementation. That is why so many patents are paid for with "one dollar and other valuable considerations." I have the dollar bill I was given for the patent. Western civilization has piles and piles of inventions created but which never made any money for the inventor. Ideas are NOT the important thing. The crucial thing is that others get convinced that what you make is worth spending money on.

Comment: @F.Zer Let me also flip the discussion around. Something that has only 30 hours of development in it is not something that can be easily protected from someone else developing it. Someone else could see what you developed and recreate it easily. The point is that it might be hard for you to make a lot of money off of it yourself. Why should someone pay you when they could pay another developer and make it? Learn as much as you can from this process as that might be all the compensation you get.

Comment: Such a privilege to receive your replies, @David R. Thank you. Could you please clarify: "Something that has only 30 hours of development in it is not something that can be easily protected from someone else developing it. Someone else could see what you developed and recreate it easily. The point is that it might be hard for you to make a lot of money off of it yourself." If something has more than 30 hours of development is easier to protect ?

Comment: @F.Zer When trying to sell something to someone, one of the considerations that the buyer has is "is it cheaper to buy this or cheaper to make it myself?" 30 hours is something that another developer will say, "I can make it." and not buy from you. 3,000 hours is a lot harder for the in-house development team to make - especially if sold at 10% of the price to develop. When we can sell to multiple people at a cost lower than they could build it, it is a lot easier to sell. The "protection" of your product is in the cost to recreate. Large cost = large protection.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much David ! That is really insightful. By the way, I should note that this client is not a developer, but he can certainly ask another developer for a quote on the same project.